# set center spot to the right in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Im working on a webapp with google maps, but ive placed the UI over the map so the center of the map places partly under the UI.

Is it possible to set the center point to the right, like in the image below?
So when i zoom, it zooms on the right half of the map.

[image](http://test.logistats.nl/static/images/stack_Q.png)

/Edit/

ive found it, sadly David your code didnt work for me.

but ive tried the panby method and it worked for me in this way and it now pans to the right when i zoom in. thanks!

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    setTimeout(moveMap, 10);
    });

    function moveMap() {
            map.panBy(300, 0);
    }
```

Comment: i cant seem to find any in the google V3 api, so i dont know if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the maps `panBy` method, this example will cut the map in half and then into quarters. The new centre will be on the 3/4 mark of the map container. This code was developed to allow for the map container to expan in size but still centre the user marker when the map was loaded at full size but cut off.

You can play around with the numbers to get your position correct.

```
var map, // Your map object
    mapWidth = $('#map').css('width'); // Width of map container
    nCentre,
    cCentre,
    visibleWidth = 200; // Visible area in PX you want map to be centered in

// Make sure width is an Int
mapWidth = parseInt(mapWidth.replace(/px$/, ''), 10);

// Get the center of viewable area
cCentre = visibleWidth / 2;

// Create the new position variable
nCentre = cCentre - (mapWidth / 2);

// Pan the map to the centre of the visible area
if (nCentre !== 0) {
    map.panBy(nCentre, 0);
}
```

For your requirements you probably don't need to do the second calculation as you really only need to work out the offset of the visible area and map container, then pan to the new centre based on the offset.